# Defining OID causes Query Layer on PostGIS to disappear from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, postgis, arcmap, query-layer

I used query layer to load my layer from PostGIS and show it in ArcMap 10, I had two cases;

1. if I defined the OID in the configuration of connection, there was no problem with the attribute table of the layer but my layer disappeared from the map.
2. if I didn't define the OID, then the layer appeared in the map but when I try to open the attribute table of my layers the following error message occurs:

> Error reading OID form table. Reading rows has been stopped. Check
>   that the datasource is valid. OID mapped column has null value

... in the table was empty.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? What is the definition and content of the "OID" column?  Does a spatial index exist on the geometry column?

Comment: - i use PostgresSQL 9.1.
- i have a id in my table and i specify it in configuration connection.
- what do you mean by a spatial index (my table in postgis contain a identifical column (id type:serial) and a geometry column (shape type:geometry) )

Answer (score 2):

the problem is solved , i described what I did exactly ,in first i change the type of the id from the serial to integer in the table , i tried to load it with defining the OID in querylayer's advanced option, but without defining the srid or the spatial reference ,the result was: the layer appear in the map & i can open my attribute table wothout any problem,but my new prbleme now is : where i define the srid & the spatial reference of my country ; the layer disappear in the map. , so i can resume :

For case1 : the problem  in reality was my new probleme but opaid no attention ; because when I set the OID , i defined also the srid & a spatial reference for that my layer dissapear.

for case2 : the attribute table was not appear because i dont define the unique identfier field .

my new probleme is solved also, i changed the srid in PostgreSQL with UpdateGeometrySRID before importing the table , the old srid was wrong (in the PostgreSQL was 0 and in querylayer option i entered 26191). & this implies a duplication .

Comment: it's Ok ! i combined it

Answer (score 1):

I recall having this problem before with ArcMap.  In my case it was because I didn't go back in to the definition of query layer to refresh the columns.  I don't have ArcMap in front of me so forget where that is.  Try doing that or creating a completely new query layer if you haven't tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was caused by a curved polygon from the input table. I used ST_CurveToLine() on the geometry field and it solved the problem.